# Django Admin: Overriding Initial Value for Inlines

Tags: django, django-admin

One of my models has a field with a default value that I'm happy with, but I want that default value to be different within the admin. Here's my attempt at achieving this:

## models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent_field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('pk',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.parent_field_1


class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    child_field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    child_field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    child_field_3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('pk',)
        verbose_name_plural = 'children'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.child_field_1
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Child


class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = [
            'parent',
            'child_field_1',
            'child_field_2',
            'child_field_3',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'instance' not in kwargs:
            initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
            initial['child_field_3'] = '1'
            kwargs['initial'] = initial

        super(ChildForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .forms import ChildForm
from .models import Parent, Child


class ChildInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Child
    form = ChildForm


class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ChildInline]


class ChildAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ChildForm

admin.site.register(Parent, ParentAdmin)
admin.site.register(Child, ChildAdmin)
```

When I go to add a child, the "Child field 3" field is populated with "1" (instead of the model's default of "0"), which is what I want. When I go to edit a child, the "Child field 3" field is populated with whatever value is in the database, which is also what I want.

The problem I'm running into comes in when I go to add or edit a parent. If I try to add a parent, I am required to also fill out all of the child inline forms. Likewise, if I try to edit a parent, I am required to fill out all of the extra child inline forms. If I comment out the `ChildInline` class' `form = ChildForm` line, I get the correct *behavior*, but, of course, the incorrect default value ("0" instead of "1"). How can I get the correct behavior and the correct default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your field is an `IntegerField`. You must set `initial` to an integer.

When the form is permitted to be empty (which is the case here), `full_clean` is [dismissed if the form did not change](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.8/django/forms/forms.py#L359). [`has_changed()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.8/django/forms/forms.py#L413) is determined by the emptiness of [`changed_data`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.8/django/forms/forms.py#L420).

Field changes is determined by [`field.has_changed(initial, data)`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.8/django/forms/fields.py#L192) where data is passed through [`field.to_python(value)`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.8/django/forms/fields.py#L271), which returns an integer in the case of an `IntegerField`. On the other hand, `initial` is supposed to be of the right type and is kept as provided. This leads to a comparison: `has_changed = ('1' != 1)`, which returns `True`, while you expected it to return `False`.

Comment: Using `self.fields['child_field_3'].initial = '1'` instead of my code didn't make a difference. Using your debug code, the following got outputted three times: `(['child_field_3'], True)`

Comment: Wow, that was it! Thanks! My logic started out as a copy/paste from somewhere online. Somehow I got the idea that initial values were always supposed to be strings, but apparently that's not the case. Thanks again!